# How to (auto-)update a column in a table using a count query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am making an attendance management system in which there is a database with the table of all **marked** attendances and i want to count all the records to put them in another table known as `Accounts`

[image: <code>Table1</code>]
[image: Query <code>PCount</code> Datasheet]
[image: <code>PCount</code> Design View]
[image: Accounts (Table)]

I have tried running update queries to set the 'Present Count' values using a sub-query `PCount` that sorts the records out according to the usernames

I have ran `Query1` but it won't change the records in `Present Count` according to `CountOfUsername` e.g `Present Count` for `User2` should `= 3`.

`PCount`:

```
SELECT Table1.Username, Count(Table1.Username) AS CountOfUsername    FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Table1 ON Accounts.Username = Table1.Username
GROUP BY Table1.Username
```

`Query1`:

```
UPDATE Accounts INNER JOIN PCount ON Accounts.Username = 
PCount.Username SET Accounts.[Present Count] = 
[PCount.CountOfUsername]
WHERE (((Accounts.Username)=[PCount].[Username]))
```

Comment: UPDATE action cannot involve aggregate query. Shouldn't save aggregate calcs anyway. Enter transactions and calculate aggregate data when needed.

Comment: @June7 But this i am doing this in vb.net and i view the column 'Present Count' in DataGridView

Comment: Why would that make any difference? Sorry, can't help with vb.net.

Comment: The user anticipates the changes made to the count when he changes the records

Comment: I would have form in Access display the aggregate calc. If I did build structure where I wanted to save aggregate calc (never have), I would use VBA to get the value to a variable and run SQL statement built in code. Or have the query object reference textbox on form for the value.

Comment: I have never used VBA so i don't know anything about it

Comment: Too bad, so easy to learn and use. I suppose vb.net should be able to do the equivalent but I have not used it enough to know how. Can't you somehow refresh the DataGridView after record is committed?

Comment: Wait, the DataGridView is displaying field you want to save value into, not results of aggregate query? Suggest you need a different object for displaying aggregate data and refresh it after record committed.

Comment: No, the DataGridView for this only displays the records and does not allow saves. I would use your idea of refreshing the view but i have already created a query which i 'SELECT' to display data. The only problem is that this is giving me a null column and i think it may be the 'Click to add' one

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to achieve this:
In design view of the table that we want to receive values from a query:

1. we set up the field we want to update as data type 'Lookup Wizard'
2. Select '... get values from another table or query...'
3. Select our query
4. Select the field we want the values from
5. Adjust the width and set the name of the field

Comment: So you still need to 'refresh' something after new record is committed so the aggregate value will recalculate?

Comment: i actually did, but i found another solution for my problem which was: displaying data in DataGridView (VB.net) from query gave me some null columns and missing columns. I used OleDB commands to display it using a connection string